# Authenticating a user from a modal window in Laravel using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, authentication

I'm looking to authenticate a user in a Laravel app from a modal window.

All the front-end is done using jQuery and I can't change that (to Vue or React), so I need to adapt.

So far, on the backend side, my Login method looks like this:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    $validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
           'success' => false,
           'errors' => $validator->errors()
        ]);
    }

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'errors' => "Invalid credentials."
    ]);
}
```

On the front-end side the request as done as following:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   const email = $("#email").val();
   const password = $("#password").val();

   if (email != '' && password != '') {
       axios.post($("#form").attr("action"), { email: email, password: password})
           .then(response => {
               if (response.data.success) {
                   window.location.href = "http://website.dev";
               } else {
                    // check for errors and display them
               }
           });
   }
});
```

Basically it works, but I'm not very fond of the solution.

Do I have another more elegant (and even more secure, maybe?) way of implementing this?

Thanks.

Comment: the basics in every language are same as you wrote i cannot add anything else just you can show eeror messages to user too

Comment: using jwt token(passport) is the more secure way to solve this problem, if you're using front-end libraries or framework, using passport is the only trustable way to authenticate

Comment: @AmirJani, no front-end frameworks or libraries can be used except jQuery. So I guess JWT is not an option.